# How do I get a reference to a dygraph based on Div ID it was assigned to?

Tags: dygraphs

Is there a way to get a reference to the graph via the div id it was placed in?

```
new Dygraph(document.getElementById("chartxyz"),.....)
```

Since that wasnt stored to a var, (or even it if was, but i try to access it from another script)

is there a way i can get a dygraph object via that div id of chartxyz? 
I'd like to run the setSelection on it to highlight a series.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'll have to maintain the mapping yourself.

```
var dygraphs = {};
dygraphs['chartxyz'] = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("chartxyz"), .....)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to have to modify it since it was being automatically generated but I've done that and its working now. Thanks